# SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() the popup is squeezed in

Tags: ios, swift, skstorereviewcontroller

The pop up of SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() showing in my device but squeezed. See the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDexj.jpg) for more details. Does any one know how to resolve this issue ?

I just add this code in `viewDidLoad()`

```
if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
  SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
}
```

My app include 1 main UITabBarController which contains the view controller which contains 1 UICollectionView.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code you have for how you attach the view controller to your view hierarchy? Or better yet, show us your view hierarchy? There might be constraints there that are affecting the SKStoreReviewController

Comment: Can you try same code in ViewDidAppear?

Comment: @Jasmit I have tried, but the result same with before.

Comment: @tomerpacific I have updated my description.